# Having issues creating a list of unique values on one sheet and outputting on worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet at the moment with a decent size dataset of 55k rows and say 15 columns that are not all full.  What I would like to do is set up a macro on another tab, where you can select a product code from a dropdown menu.  Once you select you would click the button and the program would iterate through the dataset, adding any cell values to the array before spitting out the results.

The dataset looks something like this:

```
 prod1    code    garbage   info1   info2 ... info10    

1     23       1       k         a        b    ...      j  

2     27       1       k         a2       b    

3     57       2       k         a        b      c  

4     ...  

5  

6  

7  

8  

9  

10
```

I am trying to set the value for conditions to the value of the dropdown in claim_report sheet and iterate through column F where the ing code matches and if it finds a match, iterate horizontally over the info# columns until it hits an empty one.  At this point it would start going vertically downwards again until either it hits the last value in the table or finds another match and records the new info values.

Ideally each info value is sent to an array and printed out in cell C5:CX in the spreadsheet.  would be even better if this could remove duplicates as it goes but I am afraid I don't know enough about VBA to make it work.

So far I have tried changing values, changing classes, changing order and just can't figure out what I am doing.  Everything I have been able to find was specific and I could not get it to work.

```
    Sub refresh()
    Let ing = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("claim_report").Range("B2").Value
    Dim Claims
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    j = 0
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("fulldb").Range("F2:F56000")
        If cell.Value = ing Then
            For i = 6 To 15
                While cell.Offset(columnOffset:=i) <> ""
                    Claims(j) = cell.Value
                    i = i + 1
                    Wend
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Range("C4:C100") = Claims
End Sub
```

The reason I have the i 6->15 is because the rows are offset from the F column by 6 columns so the thought was that it was iterating through cells M2, N2, O2 ... V2  until I found a blank cell.

In some of the rows some of the info columns are blank so you could have 1,2,3,4 filled with the rest blank or 1-10 filled in which was why I chose to use a blank cell to break the function.

What I would want, using my dataset as an example is to enter code 1, have the macro create the Claims array, append the values of the columns where the code matches the input code in the other spreadsheet, [a, b,..., j,a2].  This would then be entered in the other sheet in cell C4 as a transposed list.

For instance

```
C4 : a
C5 : b
C6 : ...
C14 : j
C15 : a2
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to accomplish and how your given code works toward what you're describing. Your i loop is adding 1 each loop but that's being reset when your code reaches "next", is that intentional? Also your variables are adding more confusion for me, I can't tell where some are coming from or what they're for.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelMurphy - I can't figure out **what you're trying do** - can you please provide a before/after example, maybe some screenshots of your data? Even your sample data is confusing, as well as the verbiage you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some issues with qualifications and possibly just overcomplicated.  I think you can make this a little simpler on yourself by using row.value = row.value (or finding last column per row which is the more complicated way that it appears you are trying), once it meets your criteria.  Ensure you're using Option Explicit.

using row.value = row.value:

```
dim i as long, lrs as long, lrd as long
with sheets("source") 
    lrs = .cells(.rows.count,6).end(xlup).row 'find last row on source sheet
end with
with sheets("destination") 'claim_report?
    for i = 1 to lrs 'loop through source sheet
        if sheets("source").cells(i,6).value = .cells(2,2).value then
            lrd = .cells(.rows.count,6).end(xlup).row+1  'find last row +1 on destination sheet, where you will add output
            .rows(lrd).value = sheets("source").rows(i).value
        end if
    next i
end with
```

using defined ranges, still value=value:

```
dim i as long, lrs as long, lcs as long, lrd as long
with sheets("source") 
    lrs = .cells(.rows.count,6).end(xlup).row
end with
with sheets("destination") 'claim_report?
    for i = 1 to lrs
        if sheets("source").cells(i,6).value = .cells(2,2).value then
            lcs = sheets("source").cells(i,sheets("source").columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
            lrd = .cells(.rows.count,6).end(xlup).row+1
            .range(.cells(lrd,1).cells(lrd,lcs)).value = sheets("source").range(sheets("source").cells(i,1)sheets("source").cells(i,lcs)).value
        end if
    next i
end with
```